# How did the Cohanim manage to walk on the Copper Mizbeach?

Tags: kohen-priest, miracle, mishkan-tabernacle, fire-burning

Copper is a very good heat conductor.

In the Mishkan the outside Mizbeach was made of copper, and had a fire burning on it continuously. (Actually it's a dispute if it had 3 or 4 fires burning on it daily.)

Certain types of Avoda (Temple services) required the Cohanim to step onto the actual Mizbeach.

For example:

- Every morning they had to do *Trumat Hadeshen* - take a spoonful of ashes off the Mizbeach.
- They frequently removed all the ashes.
- They had to prepare new bonfires daily and then light them.

As we know, the Cohanim had to serve barefooted.

**How did the Cohanim walk on the copper Mizbeach without getting their feet burnt?** We don't find this mentioned as one of the miracles that happened in the Mikdash.

Comment: If the Mizbeach was covered with eonugh copper to conduct heat shouldn't it also melt (or at least transform in some way which probably can be considered as Pgam)?

Comment: Correct, copper is a good conductor of heat. That also means that it's a good ***dissipator*** of heat. And while we don't see them mentioning the feet of the kohanim as a nes, we DO see them talk about the miracle that the thin film of copper (ovei marde'a) and the wooden substrate it was sitting on didn't burn or melt at the extreme temperatures (IMHO, a much greater miracle). The large surface area of the mizbeach means that while yes, it would be rather warm on the top where the kohanim walked, the thickness of the conducting surface probably channeled enough of the heat to make it safe.

Comment: Wasn't that regarding the gold?

Comment: @Zeev, gold wouldn't be a problem, due to the size of that mizbeach; copper is still a great conductor though.

Comment: I meant, that miracle only referred to the gold coating of Mizbeach Haktoret

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky can you source the "ovei marde'a thickness"? All I have is מה מזבח הזהב שאין עליו אלא כעובי דינר זהב  from the last Daf in Chagiga - where the source of the miracle of the wood not burning is mentioned  (כמה שנים אין האור שולטת )

Comment: @DannySchoemann you have the correct reference. I was operating from memory and couldn't correct the comment when I caught myself... :) a dinar is a coin minted to a specific weight, so it would be several times thicker than, say, a copper overlay.

Comment: @Zeev it's equally applicable to the mizbeach hachitzon. The use of it by the mizbach ketores is for the specific allegory it is discussing (the nimshal) rather than an exclusion of all other mizbachos.

Comment: Weren't the mizbechot in the Batei Hamikdash made of stone? In which case, this is still a problem, but likely less-so

Comment: Was the copper on top as well, or only around the wooden retaining wall? IIRC the mizbeach was filled with earth at each stop.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I specifically mentioned Mishkan, for that very reason. But you are only correct regarding the outside Mizbeach; the inside one was of gold even in the Mikdash.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon - that would qualify as an answer - see Seforno on שמות  27:8 who says נבוב לוחות. כמו תיבה בלי שולים ובלי מכסה: כאשר הראה אותך בהר. שימלאו חללו באדמה בשעת חנייתם, ועל האדמה אש תמיד תוקד (http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01425_part_7.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2)

Comment: @DannySchoemann, I was only talking about the outer mizbeach, although I was not clear in my phrasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With thanks to [Danny Schoemann](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56701/70#comment151011_56701) who pointed me at a reference to what I’d remembered without a source.

Here is how the Torah describes the tabernacle altar ([Shemot 27:8](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01425_part_7.html#%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AAB%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7-%D7%9B%D7%96-%7B%D7%97%7D)):

> נְבוּב לֻחֹת תַּעֲשֶׂה אֹתוֹ;  כַּאֲשֶׁר הֶרְאָה אֹתְךָ בָּהָר, כֵּן יַעֲשׂוּ׃
>   ***Hollow with planks shalt thou make it**; as it hath been shown thee in the mount, so shall they make it.*

As Seforno explains (*ad loc.*),

> **נבוב לוחות.‏**
>   כמו תיבה בלי שולים ובלי מכסה׃
>   **כאשר הראה אותך בהר.‏**
>   שימלאו חללו באדמה בשעת חנייתם, ועל האדמה אש תמיד תוקד׃
>   *“Hollow with planks,”*
>   *like a box without bottom or top.*
>   *“As was shown to you on the mountain,”*
>   *that they filled its hollow space with earth when they built it, and on the earth an eternal fire burned.*

So the *kohanim* were not, after all, walking on a copper sheet that had a fire on it.